# imageresizing.net Client Cache plugin not working properly with VirtualFolder plugin

Tags: imageresizer

My Images are stored in the App_Data folder so I have used the Virtual Folder plugin. Here is the snippet from web.config:

```
<resizer>
    <clientcache minutes="2880" />
    <plugins>
      <add name="FolderResizeSyntax" />
      <add name="TinyCache" />
      <add name="VirtualFolder" virtualPath="~/MyImages" physicalPath="App_Data\Media" vpp="true" />
    </plugins>
  </resizer>
```

**The below URL exposes "Expires" header correctly**

http://localhost/MyImages/1d68ee8b-6f24-4dd3-b5ad-e0c94c8ee43e.jpg?w=1110&h=215

**The below URL exposes Expires header incorrectly as -1**

http://localhost/MyImages/resize(1110,215)/1d68ee8b-6f24-4dd3-b5ad-e0c94c8ee43e.jpg

---

**Diagnostics Information:**

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      localhost   02/05/2017 07:25:53

0 Issues detected:

Assembly use report: 

You do not seem to be using any plugins from (commerical/AGPL) editions.


Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.FolderResizeSyntax
ImageResizer.Plugins.TinyCache.TinyCachePlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.VirtualFolder

Configuration:

<resizer>
<clientcache minutes="2880" />
<plugins>
<add name="FolderResizeSyntax" />
<add name="TinyCache" />
<add name="VirtualFolder" virtualPath="~/MyImages" physicalPath="App_Data\Media" vpp="true" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, crop, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, dpi, zoom, autorotate, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/10.0 on Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.10586.0 and CLR 4.0.30319.42000
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: AMD64
Executing assembly: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Installed HttpModules: 

System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyOutputCache)
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keySession)
System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyWindowsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyFormsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyDefaultAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyRoleManager)
System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyFileAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyAnonymousIdentification)
System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyProfile)
System.Web.UrlMappingsModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlMappingsModule)
System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlRoutingModule-4.0)
System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under keyScriptModule-4.0)
ImageResizer.InterceptModule, ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null          (under keyImageResizingModule)
Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RequestLifetimeHttpModule, Autofac.Integration.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da          (under key__DynamicModule_Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RequestLifetimeHttpModule, Autofac.Integration.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da_10520903-923d-48aa-9feb-6b12366c5de4)
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key__DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_f8a79548-0754-4d88-ab62-3b1bd7ef504d)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.PageInspectorHttpModule, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key__DynamicModule_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.PageInspectorHttpModule, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a_9f19eadd-1e83-4417-b925-a280a7b04126)
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key__DynamicModule_System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_2528bc3e-20d9-4877-9d23-6d5075ff8be5)
System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule, System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key__DynamicModule_System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule, System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_a85dc663-67ab-4d14-a828-f574db7a4668)

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1080.0      Info: 4.6.1080.0
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1073.0      Info: 4.6.1073.0
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1081.0      Info: 4.6.1081.0
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1084.0      Info: 4.6.1084.0
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1064.2      Info: 4.6.1064.2
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1073.0      Info: 4.6.1073.0
System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1073.0      Info: 4.6.1073.0
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.Web.RegularExpressions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 14.0.1038.0     Info: 14.0.1038.0
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform Assembly: 1.0.4.0         File: 1.0.40419.0     Info: 1.0.4-40419
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 14.1.11107.0    Info: 14.1.11022.0.Main.b428
System.Web.WebPages                      Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.30128.0     Info: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Web.Mvc                           Assembly: 5.2.3.0         File: 5.2.30128.0     Info: 5.2.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Web.Optimization                  Assembly: 1.1.0.0         File: 1.1.40211.0    
Autofac.Integration.Mvc                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.2.242       Info: 4.0.2-CI-242
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb            Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.30128.0     Info: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Web.WebPages.Razor                Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.30128.0     Info: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure             Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime Assembly: 14.0.0.0        File: 14.1.11107.0    Info: 14.1.11022.0.Main.b428
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing Assembly: 14.0.0.0        File: 14.1.11107.0    Info: 14.1.11022.0.Main.b428
App_global.asax.9ial-0z2                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
Website.Portal                           Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1073.0      Info: 4.6.1073.0
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1082.0      Info: 4.6.1082.0
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1078.0      Info: 4.6.1078.0
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.Activities                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.ServiceModel.Activities           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
Antlr3.Runtime                           Assembly: 3.5.0.2         File: 3.5.0.2        
Autofac                                  Assembly: 4.5.0.0         File: 4.5.0.0         Info: 4.5.0-develop-00406
Autofac.Integration.Mvc.Owin             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.1.222       Info: 4.0.1-CI-222
Autofac.Integration.Owin                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.0.232       Info: 4.0.0-CI-232
Autofac.Integration.WebApi               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.1.230       Info: 4.0.1-CI-230
Autofac.Integration.WebApi.Owin          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.0.226       Info: 4.0.0-CI-226
AutoMapper                               Assembly: 6.0.2.0         File: 6.0.2.0         Info: 6.0.2-master-8b260ff1
AutoMapper.EF6                           Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0         Info: 1.0.0
CsvHelper                                Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.16.3.0        Info: 2.16.3.0
DelegateDecompiler                       Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 0.23.0         
DelegateDecompiler.EntityFramework       Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 0.23.0         
EntityFramework                          Assembly: 6.0.0.0         File: 6.1.40302.0     Info: 6.1.3-40302
EntityFramework.SqlServer                Assembly: 6.0.0.0         File: 6.1.40302.0     Info: 6.1.3-40302
GridMvc                                  Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0        
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
ImageResizer.Plugins.TinyCache           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
LinqKit                                  Assembly: 1.1.9.0         File: 1.1.9.0         Info: 1.1.9.0
LinqKit.EntityFramework                  Assembly: 1.1.9.0         File: 1.1.9.0         Info: 1.1.9.0
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core           Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.2.1.40403.0  
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.2.1.40403.0  
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin           Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.2.1.40403.0  
Microsoft.Owin                           Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies          Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security                  Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook         Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google           Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth            Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter          Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Mono.Reflection                          Assembly: 1.1.0.0         File: 1.1.0.0        
MultiSafepay                             Assembly: 0.4.0.0         File: 0.4.0          
Newtonsoft.Json                          Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 10.0.2.20802   
Owin                                     Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0            
PagedList                                Assembly: 1.17.0.0        File: 1.17           
PagedList.Mvc                            Assembly: 4.5.0.0         File: 4.5            
PaymentGateways                          Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
protobuf-net                             Assembly: 2.1.0.0         File: 2.1.0           Info: 2.1.0
reCAPTCHA.MVC                            Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
System.Net.Http.Formatting               Assembly: 5.2.3.0         File: 5.2.30128.0     Info: 5.2.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Web.Helpers                       Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.30128.0     Info: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Web.Http                          Assembly: 5.2.3.0         File: 5.2.30128.0     Info: 5.2.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Web.Http.Owin                     Assembly: 5.2.3.0         File: 5.2.30128.0     Info: 5.2.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Web.Http.WebHost                  Assembly: 5.2.3.0         File: 5.2.30128.0     Info: 5.2.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Web.Razor                         Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.30128.0     Info: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
UtilityFuntions                          Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
WebGrease                                Assembly: 1.6.5135.21930 
Website.Database                         Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Website.Models                           Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Website.Services                         Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
System.Xaml                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1084.0      Info: 4.6.1084.0
System.Net.Http                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
SMDiagnostics                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.ServiceModel.Internals            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Transactions                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1080.0      Info: 4.6.1080.0
System.Numerics                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.Data.OracleClient                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.Data.Linq                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
System.Web.DataVisualization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1038.0      Info: 4.6.1038.0
EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Website.Models Assembly: 1.0.0.0
```